# Where to Place AWS ELB for Splunk deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, splunk

I have questions around AWS ELB for splunk deployment , I am building an enterprise deployment for Splunk on AWS. My question is which type of ELB should I select and in which all subnets I should place an ELB?

Comment: Have you read the deployment guide? See https://s3.amazonaws.com/quickstart-reference/splunk/enterprise/latest/doc/splunk-enterprise-on-the-aws-cloud.pdf

Comment: I read this , all the instances are in the public subnet which would not be a case in an enterprise deployment. We would place all our splunk instances in private subnet.

Comment: So you have VPN or Direct Connect into the VPC?

Comment: No, I am building in my own VPC not for the corporate network. The application will be directly hit from the internet .

Answer (score 0):

Use an Application Load Balancer (ALB) - its newer than the "Classic" Elastic Load Balencer (ELB) - but both should work.

When creating a ELB or ALB there's no harm in selecting all Availability Zones within the region even if you only plan to deploy instances to some of the available AZ's.